# Why don't I need to put return type for this swing helloworld?

Tags: java, swing, return-type

I just tried Java Swing helloworld, but I found a question with the following code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new HelloWorldFrame();
    }
    HelloWorldFrame() {

        JButton jbtnButton = new JButton("Button 1");

        jbtnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HelloWorldFrame.this, "You must click at least once!",
                          "Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);              
            }
        });

        this.add(jbtnButton);

        this.setSize(500, 500);
        // pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

So...my question is simple, how come I don't need to put return type for "HelloWorldFrame()" ?

Is there a reason or is it just a rule in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `HelloWorldFrame()` is a constructor of the `HelloWorldFrame` class, and Java constructors, like constructors in most (all?) languages with objects, don't have return values.

Comment: // what is the difference between Main() and HelloWorldFrame()? main() get executed first then main() executes HelloWorldFrame()...it confuses me. I always thought a constructor executed first.

Comment: @Moon `Main` is a not a constructor. It is a "well known method" that Java knows to call to "start" the application. There is no "Main object" created. Note that `Main` is a *static* method.

Comment: No, constructors are not executed first.  They are only executed when an object is instantiated.  `main()` is a **static** method of `HelloWorldFrame` and so can be called without needing an instance of `HelloWorldFrame` in existence.

Answer (score 1):

HelloWorldFrame() is the constructor for the class.  Java's convention is to have the constructor's be the name of the class with no return type.

See a bit more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)...

Answer (score 1):

`HelloWorldFrame()` is a constuctor. It is a special method, because it's one and only purpose is to initialise your `HelloWorldFrame` object whenever you create one.

There's probably several reasons why constructors don't return values, but the main one is because conceptually they don't return anything - they just initialise your class, and that's it.

When your object is created, the constructor is called. By the time the constructor is called though, the object already already exists, so there's no point (for example) returning a `HelloWorldFrame` instance.

Answer (score 1):

`HelloWorldFrame()` is Constructor of a class "*HelloWorldFrame*" So in java It's a rule that Constructor doesn't have any return type